# JAXB generating unwanted @XMLValue

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2, maven-jaxb2-plugin

Been grappling with a problem for about half a week now, and need help as I cannot seem to make any headway.

I've inherited an application which hasn't been treated nicely for 8 years....still on Java 1.4, Maven1 build, no new unit tests for 8 years...

Currently the upgrade to Java 1.6 (Java 1.8 branch also done in parallel, will test both) and Maven 3.3.3 is well in swing - have been making excellent headway.

Now I've hit a wall and not made a breakthrough for a while.

The old sources used local JAXB 1.3 jars to generate classes from a large XSD.

I had to migrate from JAXB1.3 to JAXB2.1 - which also meant i had to spend a lot of time rewriting all the references to the generated classes as the naming conventions changed.
Anyway, a lot of time was spent getting the code to compile.

Finally, it compiles, and I try out a unit test to see how it works.
This is where i hit my problem.

Most of the classes compiled work fine, but three of the packages throw exceptions when i try to generate the JAXBContext:

@XmlValue is not allowed on a class that derives another class.

I've narrowed the problem down to a pattern which occurs in a couple of the generated classes.
The class that causes the exception is defined in the schema as below:

```
    <xs:element name="ContactName">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="First" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Middle" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Last" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and then this element is referenced in another as follows:

```
<xs:element name="ContactInfo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:documentation>Common contact information</xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="ContactName" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element ref="ContactID" minOccurs="0"/>
            <xs:element ref="ContactDivision" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            .....
```

this is generated into:

ContactName:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "value"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ContactName")
public class ContactName
    extends BaseJaxbDoc
    implements Serializable, Cloneable, CopyTo
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 47110815L;
    @XmlValue
    protected String value;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "First")
    protected String first;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Middle")
    protected String middle;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Last")
    protected String last;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name")
    protected String name;
```

And then declared in ContactInfo as follows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
    "contactName",
    "contactID",
    "contactDivision",
    "contactPhone",
    "contactPhoneHome",
    "contactPhoneMobile",
    "contactFax",
    "contactEmail",
    "contactEmail2"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ContactInfo")
public class ContactInfo
    extends BaseJaxbDoc
    implements Serializable, Cloneable, CopyTo
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 47110815L;
    @XmlElement(name = "ContactName")
    protected List<ContactName> contactName;
```

The exception thrown is at:

```
this problem is related to the following location:
    at protected java.lang.String xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.ContactName.value
    at xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.ContactName
    at protected java.util.List xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.ContactInfo.contactName
    at xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.ContactInfo
    at protected java.util.List xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.CustomerReference.contactInfo
    at xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.CustomerReference
    at protected java.util.List xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.Item.customerReference
    at xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.Item
    at public xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.Item xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.ObjectFactory.createItem()
    at xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.orders.jaxb.ObjectFactory
```

There is an XML transformation on the original schema, stripping comments out and creating jaxb:typesafeEnum types. Then the transformed schema is used with a jxb binding file to bind everything to an internal jaxb helper superclass - BaseJaxbDoc

```
        <jaxb:globalBindings generateIsSetMethod="true">
        <xjc:serializable uid="47110815"/>
        <xjc:superClass name="xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.helpers.BaseJaxbDoc"/>
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.math.BigDecimal" xmlType="xs:decimal" 
             parseMethod="xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.helpers.AmountConverter.parseAmount" 
            printMethod="xxx.xx.xxxx.xxxx.helpers.AmountConverter.printAmount"/>
        </jaxb:globalBindings>
```

This is because I am using xjc on 9 different schemas, all generating JAXB packages of classes.

The classes all have the same superclass (defined in a bindings file for each schema) to only implement the JAXB marshall/unmarshall classes once, along with some other helper functions.
So my question is how to get around this exception when i cannot modify the schema?
Something in the XSLT or something in the bindings file?

My Maven dependencies:
for JAXB:
                org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2
                maven-jaxb21-plugin
                0.13.0

JAXB runtime:
            
            org.glassfish.jaxb
            jaxb-runtime
            2.2.11

Comment: How and why do you produce extends BaseJaxbDoc? Does it work if you remove that?

Comment: Thanks for replying, I'll update the question to add this info too.

There is an XML transformation on the original schema, stripping comments out and creating jaxb:typesafeEnum types. Then the transformed schema is used with a jxb binding file to bind everything to an internal jaxb helper superclass - BaseJaxbDoc

This is because I am using xjc on 9 different schemas, all generating JAXB packages of classes.

The classes all have the same superclass (defined in a bindings file for each schema) to only implement the JAXB marshall/unmarshall classes once, along with some other helper functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try annotating `BaseJaxbDoc` with `@XmlTransient`.

The problem you're getting is produced [here](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/adc29a8291c56e72bd52e523d906b3dab05c7b24/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ClassInfoImpl.java#L347-L350):

```
                if(getBaseClass()!=null) {
                    builder.reportError(new IllegalAnnotationException(
                        Messages.XMLVALUE_IN_DERIVED_TYPE.format(), p ));
                }
```

JAXB thinks your `BaseJaxbDoc` is a base class. So you should either remove `xjc:superClass` or trink JAXB into thinking that your class does not have a base class.

When I look at [this part of the code](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/blob/69471fb27af6a9e990ef2a7873aab64a18e87640/jaxb-ri/runtime/impl/src/main/java/com/sun/xml/bind/v2/model/impl/ModelBuilder.java#L252-L256) in the `ModelBuilder`:

```
        if(reader.hasClassAnnotation(clazz,XmlTransient.class) || isReplaced) {
            // handle it as if the base class was specified
            r = getClassInfo( nav.getSuperClass(clazz), searchForSuperClass,
                    new ClassLocatable<C>(upstream,clazz,nav) );
        }
```

It seems that the `ModelBuilder` recognizes `@XmlTransient` on classes and does not consider them. So there's a chance that assing `@XmlTransient` on your `BaseJaxbDoc` would help.

Another option is to drop `BaseJaxbDoc` construct. You use class inheritance to add marshal/unmarshal functionality to the schema-derived classes. I'd rather move this functionality out into some external services. This is probably not an option here as you're probably facing a lot of legacy code.

A further option is to try MOXy instead of JAXB RI in the runtime.

Comment: Again, thanks a lot for taking time to help me out!

Unfortunately XMLTransient didn't help - I ended up with a lot more exceptions....due to properties in the BaseJaxbDoc class.

I'd love to drop this base class, but as you said - it's a lot of rework.
Ideally I'd get everything running in a updated build environment before re-engineering.

I'll give the MOXy implementation another go - that needs Java 1.7+ to run, so I'll 
Have seen a few references to that implementation, I did try it but backed off when more exceptions popped up.
Decided I'd see if I could crack the @XMLValue one instead.

Comment: MOXy exceptions: 

javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Provider org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory could not be instantiated: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
Exception Description: The property or field value cannot be annotated with XmlValue since it is a subclass of another XML-bound class.
 - with linked exception:
[Exception [EclipseLink-50011] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JAXBException
Exception Description: The property or field value cannot be annotated with XmlValue since it is a subclass of another XML-bound class.]

Comment: looks like I'm left with no alternative but to rework the module without the BaseJaxbDoc....
Thanks for all the help, I'll spend some time investigating this with the MOXy implementation for a while before getting rid of BaseJaxbDoc.

Comment: OK....I also tried removing the XJC:superclass binding from the bindingfiles and it has stopped the exceptions being thrown at runtime...
So thanks a lot! You have shown me how to stop the rt exceptions, wonderful!
Now it's up to me to do some work and investigate what side-effects this has - as the unit test was marshalling/unmarshalling the test xml just fine!
I very much appreicate you taking the time this morning for me, hope i can one day return the favour!